# Rails How to upload precompiled assets to Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, asset-pipeline, amazon-cloudfront

- I'm using a Rails 3.2 app
- I created a Cloudfront distribution with a
  S3 origin
- I already change config.action_controller.asset_host to my
  cloudfront asset
- I'm using capistrano

I want to know, how to upload my precompiled assets to Cloudfront every time I deploy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no need for the s3 bucket as Amazon Cloudfront now supports "custom origins". It used to be that you had to specify a s3 bucket as the origin, but now you can point your cloudfront distribution at your rails app.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-custom-origins.html

So, after you create a distribution that is pointed at your publicly accessible app, you set your asset host in the appropriate config file e.g. production.rb and you are off to the races.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "url of your cloudfront distribution"
```

Here is a half decent article on how to configure things:

http://ryantownsend.co.uk/post/13126016608/cloudfront-cdn-on-rails

Don't be confused with the bit about setting up CNAME recprds for an origin subdomain. This is only relevant if you want to use your own subdomain instead of amazons.

Comment: The way the custom origins works is Cloudfront acts as a proxy to your static content. You configure Rails to serve static content from the cloudfront url, but you don't copy anything. Then when a user requests the static content from cloudfront, cloudfront says "I don't have that file, I'll get it from the app", it downloads the file from your site and then serves it up. From then on all requests for that static item come from cloudfront without bothering your app.

Comment: The above is the best approach to serving rails assets via Cloudfront with distributed servers unless you have very large assets, a lot of servers, need to work on the assets after they've been compiled, or need the old versions of assets to stick around. In those cases, use the asset_sync gem.

Answer (score 15):

After installing the aws-s3 gem, you can add this at this end of your capistrano recipe :

```
set :cdn_user, "KEY ID" # This is called "CDN KEY API" for AWS
set :cdn_api_key, "YOUR KEY SECRET"
set :cdn_container, "bucket name"

namespace :assets do
    task :to_cdn do
      require 'aws/s3'
      AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => cdn_user, :secret_access_key => cdn_api_key )
      assets_dir = "#{shared_path}/assets"
      Dir.glob(assets_dir + "/**/*").each do |file|
        if !File.directory?(file)
          cdn_filename = file.gsub(assets_dir,"assets")
          AWS::S3::S3Object.store(cdn_filename, open(file) , cdn_container)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Using a trigger like this :

```
after "deploy:assets:precompile", "assets:to_cdn"
```

You will also need to launch the compilation at some point in your recipe with :

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Result : at the end of your asset compilation, all your assets are going to be pushed on S3, and you will be able to access them from cloudfront.

You then have to update your config/environment/production.rb to point to your CDN URL.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks keyz, thats a great solution, but I have a little doubt, What happend to assets when I deploy again, I mean, Will I have problems with cache assets or expiration headers?

Comment: Assets are fingerprinted in production (a md5 hash is added to the name) so you can keep all the versions of your assets in the same folder. Magic of the assets pipeline. This prevent caching problem on update: old versions are persisting, new is still available.

Comment: You should also read the full doc on the asset pipeline : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I understand... the last question is, what happend I want to mantain only the newest version?
thanls in regards.

Comment: This is what I do for my client : I only maintain the newest version. You have to understand that some proxy might cache your website for few seconds/minutes, and you can redeploy between a user downloaded the index.html and the moment he will download your CSS or JS files. In this case, those CSS and JS will still be available ... so you can redeploy in the middle of a rush (tested approved and advertised on tv)

Comment: For more details on why this is good for you, see : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care

Comment: Amazon now supports "custom origins", so no need for all of this. It is much easier, see my answer below.

Comment: Fantastic write up. Cheers Julien.

Answer (score 3):

There's a great Ruby gem that handles this called [AssetSync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync).  If you combine it with [turbo-sprockets](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3), you can make sure that only new or updated assets are copied on deploy.